# What is the difference between internal and external links when using Dynamic Message Routing?

Tags: solace

I've read the DMR description here (https://docs.solace.com/Features/Dynamic-Msg-Routing.htm). I'm finding a bit of trouble finding clear pros/cons between the use of internal links and external links. For my use case I have multiple remote appliances, so when I first heard of DMR I thought I would cluster some of those appliances up with internal links and then connect the clusters with external links. Playing around with it in my dev environment, and further reading reveals that I can't mix and match link types. Is the best practice in this case just creating one cluster and adding all of the routers to it, or creating multiple single node clusters and connecting them with external links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing internal links and external links will be supported in a future release, which would resolve the main issue I was having.